# Keras ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory doesn't find images

Tags: deep-learning, keras, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network

I'm working on a deep learning (CNN) problem. I have structured my images into folders correctly (I think), like this:

```
train_dir:
   - class 1
   - class 2
validation_dir:
   - class 1
   - class 2
test_dir:
   - class 1
   - class 2
```

The images are PNG in a (196,256,3) format but will I'd like to convert them to (196,256,1) because they are grayscale. I do this with the `flow_from_directory` argument `color_mode='grayscale'`

As such the code I have so far to get on with this is:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # re-scale pixel values between [0,1]
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size = (196,256),
        color_mode='grayscale',
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size = (196,256),
        color_mode='grayscale',
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary')
```

With `train_dir` and `validation_dir` being strings with the equivalent path of the correct folders I mentioned earlier above.

However I get this error when running this section of the code:

```
Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes
```

After trying for sometime I can't figure out what's wrong. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: maybe the images are stored in subdirectories inside your two directories?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

Always be sure you have '.png' or whatever other file extension you are using at the end of your filename

Answer (score 0):

Please add class name under classes=(' ', ' ')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_dir,
target_size = (196,256),
color_mode='grayscale',
batch_size=20,classes=('class 1','class 2')
class_mode='binary')